# qual a maneira mais indicada ../../ ou http://?

Tags: html5, semântica

***gostaria de saber qual a maneira mais indicada?
 usar o ../../ para voltar as pastas ou [http://meu-endereço](http://meu-endere%C3%A7o) direto ?
 to com um site todo pronto, mais eu usei o ../../ para voltar as páginas para alguns link. E inspecionando alguns sites, percebi que  o povo usa o http://seusite.com em vez de usar o ../***

Comment: A mais indicada é a certa para cada caso (depende do contexto de cada situação). Para mais detalhes, clique no link do quadro de fechamento.

Comment: em quais os caso que são indicado cada uma das opções?